# Minimal DFA produced by equivalent theorem vs Myhill nerode theorem are different. What is happening?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

The problem is-:
[image]

Site 1 solves this in this way-:
https://onlinesmarttrainer.blogspot.com/2020/08/minimization-of-dfa-solved-example.html

Site 2 solves this in different way-:

https://aswaddev.github.io/dfa-minimizer/

[image]

Book solves (using table filling method) and gets this-:
[image]

Here is the youtube video, which uses Myhill Nerode method and tallies with my answer as well-:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JORJffsG4B0

My answer tallies with the blogspot one.

Why are all answers different to each other? If you know the method which is correct, can you tell in brief about that method or link some study material for that method?

Comment: The minimal DFA is unique, so there may be a mistake in typing the input somewhere.

Comment: I had added ss of the transition table. I'm sure that is not incorrect. Can you see the edited question? I added youtube channel link which solves using table filling method and gets the same answer like I do.

Answer (score 1):

The second online tool seeminly contains a code bug. It makes $F$ and $A$ states equivalent, but $0$-transition from $F$ is to the final state, while $0$-transition from $A$ is to the non-final state $B$. The same bug is with the state $D$.

The table from the book is equivalent to the first solution up to the node renaming.

Comment: my english is not very good. can you tell me which is correct? the book one and the blogspot one seems correct at this time to me..and youtube one

Comment: @jewkes https://aswaddev.github.io/dfa-minimizer/ contains a bug, all the others are correct and give equivalent answers.